# Azure Sentinel: How to convert the existing log analytics as Azure Sentinel workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I have a centralized log analytics workspace to which all the logs are being sent including:

1. Activity Logs
2. Network Logs
3. Resource Logs
4. System Metrics
5. Application Logs
6. Application Insights

Now, I want to use this log analytics workspace as a sentinel workspace so that I don't have to connect the individual resources.

Is this achievable? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a centralized log analytics workspace can be used as a Sentinel workspace to expedite log analysis and monitoring without having to connect to different resources separately.

To achieve this, create a Microsoft sentinel in the portal, link the workspaces that need to be linked while creating the sentinel, and enable `UEBA`. as detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/enable-entity-behavior-analytics).

To enable this, go to `Microsoft sentinel -> configuartion -> settings`. you need to have either a global administrator or a security administrator privilege as shown.

[image]

To connect the workspace logs to sentinel, scroll to `Data connectors` then search for Azure activity logs that need to be linked with sentinel. Then as shown, it redirects you to the connector page.

[image]

Once it is done, you can create workbooks and analytic rules which allows you to create a dashboard to visualize data and notify security alerts.

You can also query the individual workspace logs linked to the Sentinel as shown below.

[image]

[image]

Refer these [Microsoft sentinel](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/sentinel/best-practices-workspace-architecture.md) & [Microsoft Q&A](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel/send-to-sentinel-logs-from-many-log-analytics/m-p/2802576#M8450)  for more relevant approaches for this requirement.